# How to set SPN in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, spn

We are trying to set up SPNs for SQL SSRS in an environment that only has Azure AD. If I ran the SETSPN -S

MSCRMSandboxService/TESTCRM domain\crmtestserv

SETSPN -S MSCRMSandboxService/TESTCRM.symposium.org  domain\crmtestserv
I always get the message that my account has insufficient right even if the account is in the AAD DC Administrators group.

So what would be the process to set a SPN while using Azure AD?

Comment: Did you try running as *Run as Administrator* see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1262a5f8-20da-4df2-8ced-42529ece89fa/setspn-to-add-spn-results-in-error-8344-insufficient-access-rights?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes I tried to run the Command prompt as administrator, however I still get the same error message.

Comment: So you are using AAD Domain Services?

Comment: Yes, exactly we use AAD.

Comment: Have you enabled three permissions: Validated write to service principal name, Read servicePrincipalName, and Write servicePrincipalName?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Yes the user has all three permissions. However it is still not working. Any further suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @Faruman - did you ever get an answer or manage to resolve this? I've been stuck on the same problem for a couple of days now!

Answer (score 0):

You must create new Organizational Units (OU) and place the computer and user accounts in those. Accounts in the AAD DC Computers and AAD DC Users OUs can't be configured in certain ways, inluding with setspn.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/deploy-kcd

You can create a new OU and move computers and users there with Active Directory Administration Center on a Windows VM joined to the domain. It's also worth noting that the service account you use must be created within something like Active Directory Administration Center - accounts synchronized via Azure AD won't work.